# Thread Pool using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I am creating a Chat client that is making about 500,000 user registrations by communicating with a server. The client sends a request to the server, then it sends a response back to the client after processing the request. I have implemented this using an Iterative Server and a MultiThreaded server which uses a the ExecutorService framework in Java. I have a fixed thread pool of size 10. I am now trying to measure the average number of registration responses I get back from the Server per second for the Iterative and Multi-Threaded case. I observed that I got fewer responses from the Multi-Threaded as compared to the Iterative. This does not make sense, as I have 10 threads which can simultaneously process requests on the Multi-Threaded server. I'm not sure if I am programming it wrong or if I am misunderstanding a concept here. I would appreciate some help.

**EDIT:** I tried replacing `pool.execute(new SpawnConnection(client));` with  `Thread thread = new Thread(new SpawnConnection(client)); thread.start();` and the number of responses per second decreased even further.

```
    public class MultiThreadedServer {
        public static final int THREAD_COUNT = 10;
        private static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        private static HashMap<String,Chat> chatGroup = new HashMap<String,Chat>();
    private static HashMap<String,Long> heartbeatChecker = new HashMap<String,Long>();

public static synchronized void putHeartbeat(String user){
        heartbeatChecker.put(user, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public static synchronized void putGroup(String user, Chat c){
        chatGroup.put(user,c);
    }

        public static void main(String [] args){

            ServerSocket server = null;
            Socket client;
            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            try{
                server = new ServerSocket(port);
            }catch (IOException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }

            while(true){
                try {
                    client = server.accept();
                    pool.execute(new SpawnConnection(client));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the SpawnConnectionClass:

```
public class SpawnConnection implements Runnable{
    private Socket client;
    public SpawnConnection(Socket client){
        this.client = client;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if(line.startsWith("register ")){
                if(register(line)){
                    writer.println("Registration Success");
                }
                else{
                    writer.println("Error on Registration");
                }
            }
            else{
                writer.println("Invalid request");
            }
            client.close();
        }catch(IOException e){

        }

    }


    private boolean register(String line){
        String params[] = line.split(" ");

        if(MultiThreadedServer.groupContains(params[1])){
            return false;//writer.println("Error on register: username already exists. please try again.");
        }
        else{
            try {
                MultiThreadedServer.putGroup(params[1], new Chat(params[2],Integer.parseInt(params[3])));
                MultiThreadedServer.putHeartbeat(params[1]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How many concurrent clients do you have to measure this?

Comment: I have a single client which i just executing a for loop and within the loop I have a method that calls writes to the server a register command

Comment: Then having 10 threads on the server is useless, since the server only talks to one client. And you get a worse performance because of the added complexity in the server code and the need to handle context switching and communication between the main thread and the pooled threads. Use 10 concurrent clients, and you'll probably see a difference.

Comment: also consider changing your code that works with `chatGroup` - it is not thread safe

Comment: why is it not thread safe? I am using a synchronized method